# What episode is the image that chat.SE uses for the not found from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

When you try to head to a page that doesn't exist on chat.SE, it gives you a 404 page, with something like:

> We couldn't find the page you requested. We did, however, find some guys with an even more serious problem.
>
> Try searching for a particular message
>   Browse the available rooms
>   Occasionally, messages or rooms may be removed for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etcetera.
>
> If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.

And this image:

[image: 404_funny_hats.jpg (that's what SE named it, not me!)]

I can recognize Riker, Picard, and Worf in the image, wearing... snow hats?

**What TNG episode is this from?**